# Como mudar o tipo da classe persistida em um modelo com herança utilizando o EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, herança

Tenho o seguinte esquema de classes com herança, como exemplo:

```cs
public class Veiculo
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Descricao { set; get; }
}

public class Moto : Veiculo { }

public class Carro : Veiculo { }
```

Que gera o banco de dados com a tabela `Veiculo` e as colunas `Id`, `Descricao` e `Discriminator`.

Tenho um registro que o seu campo `Discriminator` está com o valor `Moto`. Ou seja, quando cadastrei esse registro fiz isso usando uma referência de `Moto`.

Como faço para transferir esse registro do tipo `Moto` para `Carro`?

Comment: Exclua o moto e cadastre como os dados como carro!!!

Comment: Então, a sua pergunta é muito pertinente, excelente pergunta inclusive, mas, só se você fizer uma edição manual, ou fazer uma rotina e deixar no sistema para alteração, mas, coisa prática não tem, só se eu estiver enganado mas, nunca vi

Comment: Outra fator é que isso é uma herança correto então Moto é diferente de Carro, mesmo os dois herdando de veiculo. Então os campos não batem, mas, sinceridade eu nunca vi tal dúvida vou até pesquisar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Momentaneamente resolvi de forma "manual".

```
var sql = " Update Veiculo Set Discriminator = @Tipo Where Id = @Id ";

myDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
    new SqlParameter("Tipo", "Carro"),
    new SqlParameter("Id", moto.Id));
```

Comment: só mais uma dica, além de alterar o discriminator também verifique quais campos são obrigatórios para que você não tenha problemas futuros. Mas, o caminho é esse mesmo parabéns